# Java Servlets + Tomcat ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlet, tomcat

Привет) у меня есть многомодульный проект, один модуль из которых - это web. Он написан на tomcat + java servlets, а так же пользуется поддержкой внедрения зависмостей spring. Каждый раз, запуская приложение, оно не может найти каке-то зависимости, указанные в pom.xml: то контекст спринга, то spring core, то apache logging. Все решалось тем, чтобы качать ручками jar-файлы этих библиотек и по одной добавлять в папку lib под WEB-INF (по мере выпадения оибок), но на последней `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.ParserContext` я уже скачать не смогла - нужно быть авторизованным где-то. Как это пофиксить? зачем мне тогда maven, если с томкат и сервлетами он не работает?

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API 4.0 for tomcat 9 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaServer Pages API 2.3 for tomcat 9 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

error stack trace:

```
15-Feb-2021 03:51:59.916 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet [catalog] as unavailable
15-Feb-2021 03:51:59.916 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [catalog]
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.ParserContext
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:689)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:561)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:105)
        at coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva.controllers.CatalogController.<init>(CatalogController.java:27)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Остальные pom:

```
<groupId>coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva</groupId>
  <artifactId>root</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>root</name>

  <modules>
    <module>shop</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>web</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--      Test-->

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.7</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

======================================================

<parent>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <groupId>coherentsolutions.nastyabakhshieva</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Может нужен какой-то плагин чтобы он с томкатом норм работал?

Comment: покажи pom'ники родительского и дочернего проекта

Comment: добавила в описание

Comment: Приложи полный pom'ник от web'а. Заодно покажи, что лежит в `${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib`